# Why is my ajax call for JSON coming back empty?

Tags: ajax, json

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('matchEngine.php',
        function(data){
        $('#results').html(data);

        alert("data gotten!");
    }, 'json');
});
```

the alert appears and I can put dummy text appear in the html eg $('#results').html("very annoying");

the php echoes a json_encode array if I just go to the page, so what am I doing wrong??

Comment: try `$('#results').html(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: @mikeB cheers also got OUTPUT visable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your callback, `data` will be the *deserialized object*, not the JSON string. So when you pass that into `html`, you're basically calling `toString` on it and passing the result. If `data` is an array, that does an `Array#join` by default. If it's an object, `toString` will give you `[object Object]`.

You should be seeing *something* in the `results` element, but the main point here is that if your goal is to work with the data in `data`, it's already been decoded for you.

If you want to see the actual JSON text that was returned by the script, you can do that by telling jQuery *not* to deserialize it for you, and by making sure when you dump it out to the HTML that any HTML entities or special characters are handled properly, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('matchEngine.php',
        function(data){
        $('#results').text(data); // <== `text` instead of `html`
                                  //     makes sure HTML characters
                                  //     like < are shown correctly

        alert("data gotten!");
    }, 'text');                   // <== data type 'text' instead of
                                  //     'json' tells jQuery NOT to decode
                                  //     it for you
});
```